# Регулярные выражения Java + JSON

Tags: java, json, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. 
Возникла необходимость изменить часть Json'а. Конкретно, нужно заменить первую букву имени ключа на маленькую. 
Т.е. сделать из `"Key" : "Value"` что-то вроде `"key" : "Value"`. 
Просто `.replace()` не подходит, т.к. заменятся не только ключи, но и значения. 
Люди, помогите. Подскажите регулярку, вроде [`"` + буква, если после идёт `:`]. Или, если я совсем ебобо, подскажите, как это сделать проще.

Comment: Получаем первый не пробельный символ строки и Character.toLowerCase(ch);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такую:

> (?<=  ")\w

[ссылка](https://regex101.com/r/Hc2wwi/1)

Comment: Спасибо! Два дня мучений только что закончились :)

Comment: Эм.. Неправда же...

Comment: Конечно, это не для всех случаев, для каждого нужно подходить точечно, по-этому я и предоставил пример, на котором подходит, так как примера того что хочет заменить автор не предоставлено.